# Raspberry Pi 3 BLE scanning failure

Tags: pi-3, linux, bluetooth, c, c++

I am trying to implement the next code to scan for BLE devices:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <bluetooth/bluetooth.h>
#include <bluetooth/hci.h>
#include <bluetooth/hci_lib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    inquiry_info *ii = NULL;
    int max_rsp, num_rsp;
    int dev_id, sock, len, flags;
    int i;
    char addr[19] = { 0 };
    char name[248] = { 0 };

    dev_id = hci_get_route(NULL);
    sock = hci_open_dev( dev_id );
    if (dev_id < 0 || sock < 0) {
        perror("opening socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    len  = 8;
    max_rsp = 255;
    flags = IREQ_CACHE_FLUSH;
    ii = (inquiry_info*)malloc(max_rsp * sizeof(inquiry_info));

    num_rsp = hci_inquiry(dev_id, len, max_rsp, NULL, &ii, flags);
    if( num_rsp < 0 ) perror("hci_inquiry");

    for (i = 0; i < num_rsp; i++) {
        ba2str(&(ii+i)->bdaddr, addr);
        memset(name, 0, sizeof(name));
        if (hci_read_remote_name(sock, &(ii+i)->bdaddr, sizeof(name), 
            name, 0) < 0)
        strcpy(name, "[unknown]");
        printf("%s  %s\n", addr, name);
    }

    free( ii );
    close( sock );
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that `num_rsp` is equal to zero, that is, it is not finding any device.

However, if I use the command `$ sudo hcitool lescan`in the terminal, it finds all the devices available.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to troubleshoot this? Is there any other way to implement `hcitool lescan` as C++ code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I got a valid answer at stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38267072/raspberry-pi-3-ble-scanning

Comment: If you've got a valid answer so please create an answer also to your question here and accept it after two days. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again and again for years.

Answer (score 1):

I notice you have already found the library [Gattlib](https://github.com/labapart/gattlib) to help you to write a C/C++ program to scan BLE devices with its example: https://github.com/labapart/gattlib/blob/master/examples/ble_scan/ble_scan.c